# How to check if all of the Maybe fields in a haskell record are nothing?

Tags: haskell

If I had a record like:

```
data MaybeTest = MaybeTest {
  test0 :: String
  test1 :: Maybe Int,
  test2 :: Maybe Float,
  test3 :: Maybe Int,
  test4 :: Maybe String,
  test5 :: Maybe String
  }
  deriving (Typeable, Data, Eq, Show)
```

is there a simple way to see if all the maybe fields are Nothing? I would like to return Nothing if the records fit this condition else return Just MaybeTest. I want to avoid my current long method of calling each Maybe field and checking if they are Nothing.

Comment: You meay, simpler than `case x of {MaybeTest _ Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing Nothing -> "YupThey'reAllNothing"; _ -> "nope" }`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes since I would like to do this generically for different sized data, and not have to write a different number of Nothings for each one

Comment: I wonder if you can do something with `type MaybeTest = PolyTest Maybe; data PolyTest maybe = PolyTest { test1 :: maybe Int, ... }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stuff like this usually requires generics.  `Data.Data` generics are generally the easiest to use.  You can define a query that checks all `Maybe x` fields with the `isNothing` predicate using:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import Data.Maybe (isNothing)
import Data.Data (Data, gmapQ)
import Data.Generics.Aliases (ext1Q)

allNothing :: (Data d) => d -> Bool
allNothing = and . gmapQ (const True `ext1Q` isNothing)
```

Here, `ext1Q` constructs a query that applies `isNothing` to any type matching `Maybe b` while applying `const True` to any non-`Maybe` type.  The `gmapQ` function maps it across all fields of the target type, resulting in a list of booleans that are `True` for all non-`Maybe` types and `Nothing` values but `False` for all `Just x` values.

You can test it like so:

```
data Foo = Foo String (Maybe Int) Char (Maybe Double) deriving (Show, Data)
data Bar = Bar (Maybe [Int]) deriving (Show, Data)
```

and in GHCi:

```
λ> allNothing (Foo "x" Nothing 'a' Nothing)
True
λ> allNothing (Foo "x" Nothing 'a' (Just 3.14))
False
λ> allNothing (Bar Nothing)
True
λ> allNothing (Bar (Just [1..10]))
False
```

With that function available, it's easy to write your desired function:

```
checkNothing :: (Data d) => d -> Maybe d
checkNothing x | allNothing x = Nothing
               | otherwise    = Just x
```

giving:

```
λ> checkNothing (Foo "x" Nothing 'a' Nothing)
Nothing
λ> checkNothing (Foo "x" Nothing 'a' (Just 3.14))
Just (Foo "x" Nothing 'a' (Just 3.14))
```

Comment: Nice. — I disagree that `Data.Data` are the easiest to use. They're much more concise and arguably more elegant than GHC.Generics, but that is straightforward to learn whereas the rank-2 signatures of `Data.Data` are quite cryptic.

Comment: I didn't expect this to work so well. I never knew `ext1Q` existed, but only `extQ` -- until now. Without that, it seemed hard-ish to extend the query without knowing the full type. I managed to to that using `eqTypeRep`, but not as elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

Not as concise as generic programming, but closer to Haskell 98 and perhaps more readable is the Maybe monad:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
data MaybeTest = MaybeTest {
  test0 :: String,
  test1 :: Maybe Int,
  test2 :: Maybe Float,
  test3 :: Maybe Int,
  test4 :: Maybe String,
  test5 :: Maybe String
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

valid :: MaybeTest -> Maybe MaybeTest
valid o@(MaybeTest{..}) = do
    _ <- test1
    _ <- test2
    _ <- test3
    _ <- test4
    _ <- test5
    pure o
```

Comment: I think the idea is that the asker doesn't want the `valid` method's length to be proportional to the number of `Maybe`s.

Comment: I think you're right, but it wasn't explicit. More solutions usually helps the learning. Sometimes people only know the solutions shared with other languages, such as N equality checks + if.